version `GLIBC_2.28' not found when running aws lambda python 3.9
Suddenly, when I run my AWS lambda, I'm getting this error:
"Unable to import module 'lambda_name': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /var/task/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)

I'm using Python runtime 3.9 with the following requirments.txt:
boto3
botocore
pycparser
pyopenssl
certifi
cffi


To solve the error, I installed the snowflake-connector-python==2.7.9 library within a temporary virtual environment. This environment was then used to create the Lambda layer zip file. Here's the command I used:


pip3 install \
--platform manylinux2010_x86_64 \
--implementation cp \
--only-binary=:all: --upgrade \
--target venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ \
 snowflake-connector-python==2.7.9 boto3>=1.26.153 botocore>=1.29.153



You may also wanted to take a look on Aws lambda returns /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

but i'm not using any snowflake connector in my case?

I was just able to fix this by removing the requirments.txt file and installing all my packages using:
pip3 install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target=pyopenssl --implementation cp --python-version 3.9 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade <package name>

